# How to change scope variable in karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a test case that `scope.action = 'Insert'` need to be changed for every it()  i.e for first test case it should be as `insert` for 2nd test case `scope.action='update'` and for the 3rd test case it should be `scope.action='delete'`. How can i achieve this.

'use strict';

describe('app module', function() {

```
beforeEach(module('sampleApp'));

beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
  $provide.value('BaseController', {});
}));

describe('TestController', function() {
  var scope, controller;
      beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
          scope = $rootScope.$new();
          controller = $controller;
          controller('BaseController', {$scope: scope});
          controller('TestController', {
          $scope: scope
      });
         scope.action="insert" ;
  }));
  it('Should return type insert', function () {
      expect(scope.getActionType()).toBe('insert');
  });
  it('Should return type update', function () {
      expect(scope.getActionType()).toBe('update');
  });
  it('Should return type delete', function () {
      expect(scope.getActionType()).toBe('delete');
  });
```

});
});

Answer (score 0):

You'd achieve it via describe's in describe's. The outer beforeEach() block sets things up, but the inner ones set your scope:

```
describe('Test Controller', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // In here, do what you currently have in your beforeEach
    // but NOT the scope.action; EXCEPT the controller;
  });

  describe('Test 1', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      scope.action = 'Insert'
      controller('TestController', { $scope: scope });
    });
    it('First Test', () => {});
  });

  describe('Test 2', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      scope.action = 'Update';
      controller('TestController', { $scope: scope });
    });
    it('Second Test', () => {});
  });

  describe('Test 3', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      scope.action = 'Delete';
      controller('TestController', { $scope: scope });
    });
    it('Third Test', () => {});
  });
});
```

Comment: value for `scope.action` is not assigning for every test casescope.action getting ' '

Comment: I've modified the answer slightly, see if that works for you @VenkatLokeswar